# sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge ERROR

Tags: apt, package-management

```
administrator@xtrapcpro64:~$ sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

That is the failure I am getting.  Confession, This is Ubuntu on a thumb drive.

```
administrator@xtrapcpro64:~$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Xtra-PC
DISTRIB_RELEASE=4.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Xtra-PC 4.1"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

**YEARS** ago, I had great luck with this tutorial:

[HOWTO: Cleaning up all those unnecessary junk files... - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=140920)

I am fine until I get to the instruction to:

```
sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge
```

Doesn't look like there is a preview option, so I hope to H this posts effectively.

Help is appreciated in advance.

Edit:
sudo deborphan returns

administrator@xtrapcpro64:~$ sudo deborphan
[sudo] password for administrator: 
libsidplayfp4
libmusicbrainz3-6v5
libmms0
libmeanwhile1
libical1a
libwv-1.2-4
libgeoclue0
libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0
libtidy-0.99-0
libexo-1-0
libgmtk1
libloudmouth1-0
libguess1
libburn4
libgtkspell0
libcue1
libfarstream-0.2-5
libqmi-glib1
libbinio1v5
libmessaging-menu0
libpisock9
libgoffice-0.10-10
libonig2
libisofs6
libzephyr4
libcompfaceg1
libevent-2.0-5
libtelepathy-glib0
lxshortcut
gnome-time-admin
libfluidsynth1
libwhoopsie0
libots0
administrator@xtrapcpro64:~$

I took the "tour" years ago .. 2006 probably.  I evidently should again and will.

no -r because I was following instructions as instructed.  I am not a proficient Linux user ... and probably never will be.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What is the result of `sudo deborphan` by itself? Why not use the `-r, --no-run-if-empty` option to `find`? "Doesn't look like there is a preview option"? Did you take the Tour? https://askubuntu.com/tour will help you ask better questions,

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  see edit in original post.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo deborphan --guess-common | xargs sudo apt purge -y
```